# Where is the memory allocated when I create this array? (C)

Tags: c, string, memory-management

Let's say I do something like:

```
char* test[] = {"foo","bar","car"};
```

What exactly is this equivalent to if I did it the long way?  Is this automatically creating memory that I will need to free?  I'm just sort of confused.  Thanks.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that you only ever need to free memory a) that you create (e.g., using `malloc` or `mmap`), or b) that is returned by a function that **explicitly documents** that you are responsible for doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` is an array of pointers to char located on the stack, and the string literals `"foo"`,`"bar"`,`"car"` are stored in a read only location. You need to free nothing.

`test[0]`, `test[1]`, `test[2]` point to read-only data. Please read about scoping rules and variable's lifetime in C. By default a variable which does not have storage-class specifier within a block has `auto` storage-class specifier which means  a variable with a local lifetime.

```
{
    char* test[] = {"foo","bar","car"};
}
//cannot access test here 
test [0] = "new"; // Compile time error - ‘test’ undeclared
```

While trying to modify "bar" to "tar" will give runtime error:

```
char* test[] = {"foo","bar","car"};
test[1][0] = "tar"; // Run-time error
```

However this is fine `test[0]` starts to point to `"new"` from `"foo"`:

```
test [0] ="new";
```

The reference to `"foo"` is lost.

Comment: So I cannot change these values if they are read-only?  Aren't I able to say test[0] = "foo2"?

Comment: The string literals are stored in read-only locations not the pointer itself. The pointer has local lifetime in the block.

Comment: One last question: what's the difference between doing "char* x" opposed to "char x[10]"?

Comment: Array of chars stores characters and can be indexed - `arr[] = "test"` means - `arr[0]=='t'`,`arr[1]=='e'`, etc, which is modifiable as opposed to a string literal which is stored in a readonly location but cannot be modified. You can point to the string literal though.

Comment: test may not be allocated on the stack. It can be static (global var).

Comment: Where in the world is the keyword static mentioned in the declaration?

Answer (score 5):

You are declaring an array of pointers. The pointers point to string literals.

The variable `test` follows the normal rule, if it's an automatic variable(scope inside some function), when out of the function, it gets out of scope, so you don't have to free the memory. If it's statically allocated(global or `static` variable), it has a life as long as the program, so you don't have to free the memory either.

The string literals that the pointers point have static storage, so you don't free them either.

Answer (score 0):

The long way is to use malloc, and malloc the size of a string.

test will be pushed onto the heap

http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html

Comment: `malloc` allocates memory on the heap; it is incorrect or at least misleading to say that “`malloc` would push it onto the stack.”

Answer (score 0):

`Test` is an array of `charecter pointers`.When an initialization of values is provided for an array, C allows the possibility of leaving the square brackets empty [ ]. In this case, the compiler will assume a size for the array that matches the number of values included between braces `{ }` .There is no need to free.